# как правильно подключить класс, через конструктор?

Tags: php, slim

Я пишу один контроллер для главной страницы, и у меня не получается добавить туда классы.
Так же я использую в этом проекте шаблонизатор "Twig" и маршрутизатор Slim.
И вот такую ошибку выдает Slim:

'**Type:** ArgumentCountError
**Code**: 0
**Message:**  Argument 1 passed to Blog\Route\HomePage::__construct() must be an instance of Blog\LatestPosts, null given, called in D:\web-programmig\OpenServer\domains\testsite\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\CallableResolver.php on line 154
**File:** D:\web-programmig\OpenServer\domains\testsite\src\Route\HomePage.php
**Line:** 19'

Вот мой код контроллера:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Blog\Route;

use Blog\LatestPosts;
use Blog\OtherClasses\ApiClass;
use Blog\OtherClasses\CookiesClass;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use Twig\Environment;

class HomePage
{
    private LatestPosts $latestPosts;
    private Environment $view;
    private CookiesClass $cookie;
    private ApiClass $weatherData;

    public function __construct(LatestPosts $latestPosts, Environment $view,
                                CookiesClass $cookie, ApiClass $weatherData)
    {
        $this->latestPosts = $latestPosts;
        $this->view = $view;
        $this->cookie = $cookie;
        $this->weatherData = $weatherData;
    }

    public function execute(Request $request, Response $response): Response
    {
        $posts = $this->latestPosts->get(3);

        $body = $this->view->render('index.twig', [
            'posts' => $posts,
            'cookie' => $this->cookie->getUsernameCookie(),
            'regCookie' => $this->cookie->getRegCookie(),
            'weatherData' => $this->weatherData->getWeatherData('Kostanay')
        ]);
        $response->getBody()->write($body);
        return $response;
    }
}
```

Я долго пытался разобраться, но ничего в голову не пришло. Это важный для меня проект так, как это мой первый сайт. Надеюсь на вашу помощь. Заранее большое спасибо.

Comment: `Too few arguments to function Blog\Route\HomePage::__construct(), 1 passed in ... and exactly 2 expected`  - _слишком мало аргументов для функции конструктора класса Blog\Route\HomePage, 1 передан в ... и именно 2 ожидаются_. - давайте подумаем, в чём может быть ошибка?

Comment: Но я ведь передал 4 аргумента. Я не могу понять почему он пишет что я передал 1.

Comment: Добавьте код где мы можем увидеть что как и куда передаёте

Comment: Да, вот весь код моего проекта: https://github.com/archefnx/TopSite . Ошибка выходит в /src/Route/HomePage

Comment: Делать мне нечего, кроме как разбираться в проекте вашем?.. Ошибка возникает при вызове класса HomePage, этот код что в вопросе бесполезный, это ожидания, ожидается одно, а при вызове передаётся другое

Comment: Да, тут согласен. Ошибка говорит что вместо класса передается null, хотя php DI я вроде правильно подключил: ```

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно использовать контейнер зависимостей для этих целей. В Slim 3 используется pimple, в 4й версии его по умолчанию нет, но можно добавить любой, реализующий интерфейс psr/container.

Вам нужно добавить контроллер в контейнер, примерно так (зависит от конкретного контейнера, в примере pimple):

```php
<?php

$container[\Blog\Route\LatestPosts::class] = function(\Pimple\Container $pimple) {
    return new \Blog\Route\LatestPosts(
        // тут параметры LatestPosts 
    );
};

$container[\Twig\Environment::class] = function(\Pimple\Container $pimple) {
    return new \Twig\Environment(
        // тут параметры twig        
    );
};

$container[\Blog\OtherClasses\CookiesClass::class] = function(\Pimple\Container $pimple) {
    return new \Blog\OtherClasses\CookiesClass(
        // тут параметры кук
    );
};

$container[\Blog\OtherClasses\ApiClass::class] = function(\Pimple\Container $pimple) {
    return new \Blog\OtherClasses\ApiClass(
        // тут параметры апи
    );
};

$container[\Blog\Route\HomePage::class] = function(\Pimple\Container $pimple) {
    return new \Blog\Route\HomePage(
        $pimple[\Blog\Route\LatestPosts::class],
        $pimple[\Twig\Environment::class],
        $pimple[\Blog\OtherClasses\CookiesClass::class],
        $pimple[\Blog\OtherClasses\ApiClass::class]
    );
};
```

А в роутах указываете нужный метод

```php
$slim->get('/', \Blog\Route\HomePage::class . ':execute');

// с версии 4.8 можно так:
$slim->get('/', [\Blog\Route\HomePage::class, 'execute']); // тогда в шторме по ctrl+click можно будет проваливаться в метод
```